# solve a differential equation numerically

Tags: differential-equations

I have to solve numerically an equation of the form

```
M1 = Array[Subscript[y, #1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}];
M = {{m1^2, 0}, {0, m2^2}};
DSolve[{i D[M1, t] == (M.M1 - M1.M)/20}, Variables[M1], t]
```

Now how to provide the initial conditions in this case and also I have the value of `(m1^2-m2^2)` but not the individual values of `m1^2` and `m2^2`. In this case, how to proceed?

Comment: If we have **m1^2-m2^2 = m0** we can make the substitution **DSolve[{i D[M1, t] == (M.M1 - M1.M)/20}, Variables[M1],  t] /. {m1^2 -> m00 + m2^2}** The initial values can be handled also with the substitution command

Comment: Generally one avoids [starting your own variables with capital letters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999).